# Typus Gem Rails 3 How to set path(other than "/admin")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, rubygems, admin

I have been working with the latest version of typus(3.0.3) for Ruby on Rails. Setting the path used to be set this way

Typus::Configuration.options[:path_prefix] = 'backoffice'

so that "http://localhost:3000/admin" would become this "http://localhost:3000/backoffice" to gain access to the admin system.

So basically i cant find a way to set this in the new version. Any ideas on how to set this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Sad to say, but it doesn't look like this is possible. I just scanned through the Typus source (branch '3-0-stable') and "admin/" is hardcoded all over the place.